# Plotly Scatter Plot: Symbol disrupts the colorscale and categorical x-y positions

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly, r-plotly

I'm creating a unique type of categorical scatter plot with plotly in R, where:

- color is indicated by a continuous numeric variable
- size is indicated by a continuous numeric
- symbol is indicated by a categorical
- both axis are categorical variables

It appears that calling "symbol" and "symbols" is affecting the color scale numbers as well as the proper location of markers.

Here is my demo code which includes hoverinfo so you can see that the "NA" for Top/C is not in the correct position.

```
library(plotly)

m <- data.frame(c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),
                c('Top','Bottom','Top','Bottom','Top','Bottom'),
                c('OK','NG','OK','OK','OK','NG'),
                c(8,20,55,72,NA,43),  # Top,C should be blank
                c(4,5,6,7,8,9))
colnames(m) <- c("cat_1","cat_2","check","Bigness", "Twistiness")

color_scale <- list(c(0,'rgb(227,120,0)'),c(0.5,'rgb(220,220,220)') , c(1,'rgb(43,92,138)')) 

p <- plot_ly(data = m,
             x = ~cat_1,
             y = ~cat_2,
             type='scatter',
             mode='markers',
             symbol = ~check,  ##  problem line
             symbols = c('square-open','square'), ##  problem line
             marker = list(color = ~Twistiness, 
                           size= ~Bigness,
                           colorscale = color_scale,
                           colorbar = list(len = 0.8, y = 0.3)),
             text = ~paste0('cat_1 (x): ', cat_1, '\n',
                            'cat_2 (y): ', cat_2, '\n',
                            'Big (size): ', Bigness, '\n',
                            'Twist (color): ', Twistiness, '\n')
             ) %>%
  layout(margin = list(r = 8, t = 15, b = 50, l = 80),
         # xaxis = list(title = ""), 
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         showlegend = TRUE)
p
```

[Picture of executed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGsTt.png)

It seems that plotly is the best way to add interactive hover as well as pass event_data to another code block in Shiny.
I have tried this via ggplotly, but the event_data is not correct and the legend cannot have custom positioning.

Comment: when I run size= ~Bigness outside the marker = list, it works.

Comment: The color scale still still has label overlap and does not get corrected when moved outside the marker=list.  However, this did correct the positioning problem.